# What is the Rider equivalent of Navigate Backward and Navigate Forward commands of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, rider

I've been using Rider on mac and it is awesome. But there is a feature I miss a lot. The "Navigate Backward and Navigate Forward commands of Visual Studio".
Could anyone please tell me its equivalent in Rider?
I've googled and found [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Navigating_to_Recent_Locations.html#navigating-vcs-changes)
And they mention this as a shortcut "⌃⌥⇧↓" that is; ctrl+alt+shift+down but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone please tell me its equivalent in Rider?

This depends on your selected predefined keymap, which can be changed under **JetBrains Rider | Preferences | Keymap** - see [Settings_Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Keymap.html?keymap=secondary_macos_system_shortcuts).

---

Examples for [*Context Navigation Back/Forward*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_macos_system_shortcuts#context_navigation) depending on the predefined keymap:

| Keymap | Action | Shortcut |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [VSCode (macOS)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_vscode_macos#context_navigation) | Context navigation - Back | <kbd>⌃-</kbd> |
|  | Context navigation - Forward | <kbd>⌃⇧-</kbd> |
| [macOS System](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_macos_system_shortcuts#context_navigation) | Context navigation - Back | <kbd>⌘[</kbd> |
|  | Context navigation - Forward | <kbd>⌘]</kbd> |
| [Visual Studio (macOS)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_visual_studio_macos#context_navigation) | Context navigation - Back | <kbd>⌘-</kbd> |
|  | Context navigation - Forward | <kbd>⇧⌘-</kbd> |
| [ReSharper (macOS)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_resharper_macos#context_navigation) | Context navigation - Back | <kbd>⌘-</kbd> |
|  | Context navigation - Forward | <kbd>⇧⌘-</kbd> |
| [Visual Assist(macOS)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_visual_assist_macos#context_navigation) | Context navigation - Back | <kbd>⌘-</kbd> |
|  | Context navigation - Forward | <kbd>⇧⌘-</kbd> |

You can find an overview over all predefined keymaps in the Rider documentation under [Keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference_Keyboard_Shortcuts_Index.html?keymap=secondary_visual_studio_macos). To get the correct binding list for your keymap, you can change it in the upper right corner.

[image: Predefined keymaps from jetbrains help]

---

You could find cheatsheets provided by JetBrains at the left bottom of the [Rider Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/documentation/).

For example:
[Mac OS X 10.5+ Keymap](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/rider/docs/Rider_macosx_shortcuts.pdf).